# Thingsboard OTA : How to update firmware of the IoT devices via GSM or Bluetooth using Thingsboard?

Tags: firmware, thingsboard, over-the-air

I am working on a POC project that has following configurations,

1. Two types of IoT devices : Device with built-in GSM module, Device with Bluetooth Module
2. A Mobile Phone with Android OS
3. Thingsboard

I would like to update the firmware of these IoT devices via Mobile Phone as well as from Thingsboard Dashboard.

- Mobile Phone connects to IoT devices via Bluetooth.
- Thingsboard connects to IoT devices via GSM

For this kind of project configuration, How to update firmware of IoT devices using Thingsboard?

Any suggestions, recommendations or documentation is very much welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can update firmware for device by sending version and url to download firmware to the device.
In order to make it automation, attaching version and url to device shared attribute, it will automatically send shared attribute to device whenever you update version and link for new version of FW.
Please check out example in Thingsboard: https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/esp32/ota/